# How to let XMonad treat a window as dock?

Tags: xmonad

my purpose is to make a certain vim window as a dock (stay on all screens, fixed location, won't be affected by XMonad layout, etc). So i used `xprop` to set a window as dock type. But XMonad did not seem to honor it. What else should I do?

The xprop command:

```
$ xprop -id 0x2400001 -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK
$ xprop -id 0x2400001 | grep TYPE                                                                    
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting XMonad after setting the window as a dock? Do you have `avoidStruts` in your config?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, but I do not want to restart XMonad every time I make a dock. And yes, I have avoidStruts. Dock app like taffybar works fine.

Comment: Hmm but does it work if you set that property on a window and then do a xmonad restart? That would just help identify any issues - perhaps there is something that needs to be run after that (setting a dock window) occurs.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, good point. Tried, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/732058/585364

You also need to set a strut property: `xprop -f _NET_WM_STRUT 32c -set _NET_WM_STRUT 0,300,0,0`

And you probably also need to 'move' the window to that location.

This does require an xmonad restart to take effect when I tested it.

Comment: The avoiding works, when set struts. And I can move the window into that "gap". But the window is not behaving as a dock, that is shared between all workspace.

Comment: _NET_WM_DESKTOP might be needed https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html

Comment: Made a simple dock via gtk3. Seems like the only X property difference is _NET_WM_DESKTOP. It should be gone for dock window. But for now, I could not get rid of it for a normal window. xprop set/remove did not work.